# how to disappear the middle column when zoomed out?

Tags: bootstrap-4

When I first learned about bootstrap 4, I was trying to lose the middle column when I zoomed out but it didn't seem to work, check it for me, thanks.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4  col-6">Account</div>
    <div class="col-md-2  col-0">Followers</div>
    <div class="col-md-6  col-6">Recent post</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.d-md-none .d-lg-block
```

Use this bootstrap class. More info [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/.)

Bootstrap allows you to hide elements based on md lg display etc. I used the md display but you can use whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To hide an element on the large breakpoint only use `d-lg-none`.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-6">Account</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 d-lg-none">Followers</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Recent post</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/arajay/pen/zYxEwvE)